# Creating XSD from Excel

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xslt-1.0

Is it possible to create XSD from Excel file? Basically I want to create XSD from the requirement sheet created. Requirement sheet (Excel) can be in the below format

```
ElementName Field_Type  Total_Length Required/Optional

PO_Number   Number      10           Required
PO_Desc     String      10           Required
Address     String      50           Optional
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems very simple if you can use a programming language like Java. If you can't do that then Excel provides [support for exporting data into xml](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/export-xml-data-HP010206401.aspx).

Comment: Yes, Its easily possible in Excel if the data is in XML format, then it can create schema out of it. However the data given is kind of requirement format. Its not an XML format. We need to create the schema based on the elements given and the conditions for the element. Also I've given the simple flat structure. It could be complicated requirement with multiple levels of elements. Creating the java class to parse all the rows and creating the schema might be complex i guess